# react native navigation payload error for login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am facing a issue with my login screen. Every thing works quite well But my problem is after successfully making a login i am getting a payload error. I am using a function component not a class component. And all my screens are outside the Route.js.

Error is

My Route.js code are as follows:

```
 import  React, {  useState } from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
/// All components of screens
import HomeScreen from './src/Component/HomeScreen';
import DefaultScreen from './src/Component/DefaultScreen';
import Privacy from './src/Component/Privacy';
import Signup from './src/Component/Signup';
import ForgetPassword from './src/Component/ForgetPassword';
import Dashboard from './src/Component/Dashboard';
import SplashScreen from './src/Component/SplashScreen';
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export default function Routes(){
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
  (prevState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'SIGN_IN':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          isSignout: false,
          userToken: action.token,
        };
      case 'SIGN_OUT':
        return {
          ...prevState,
          isSignout: true,
          userToken: undefined,
        };
    }
  },
  {
    isLoading: true,
    isSignout: false,
    userToken: null,
  }
);

React.useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    let userToken;

    try {
      userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@kiklee-user-id');
    } catch (e) {
      // Restoring token failed
    }

    // After restoring token, we may need to validate it in production apps

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    dispatch({ type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
  };

  bootstrapAsync();
}, []);

const authContext = React.useMemo(
  () => ({
    signIn: async data => {
      // In a production app, we need to send some data (usually username, password) to server and get a token
      // We will also need to handle errors if sign in failed
      // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
      // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

      dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
    },
    signOut: () => dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' }),
    signUp: async data => {
      // In a production app, we need to send user data to server and get a token
      // We will also need to handle errors if sign up failed
      // After getting token, we need to persist the token using `AsyncStorage`
      // In the example, we'll use a dummy token

      dispatch({ type: 'SIGN_IN', token: 'dummy-auth-token' });
    },
  }),
  []
);

if (state.isLoading) {
  // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
  return <SplashScreen />;
}
  //alert(authContext);


    return(
      <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
     {state.userToken == null ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown:false, animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push', }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Privacy" component={Privacy} options={{ headerShown:false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ForgetPassword" component={ForgetPassword} options={{  headerShown:false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={Signup} options={{  headerShown:false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} options={{ headerShown:false }} />
    </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} options={{ headerShown:false }} />

  </>
)}

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
            );



}
```

My login screen is HomeScreen.js 'HomeScreen' and After log in i am redirecting user to Dashboard.js  'Dashboard'

Comment: Error is this one https://prnt.sc/r336x7

Answer (score 0):

I think the code `await AsyncStorage.getItem('@kiklee-user-id')` returns null, so state.userToken value is always null, and your `<Stack.Navigator>` component has not any `Dashboard` route

Comment: :) no its returning the value correctly. Actually this is happening with the dispatcher. Most of the user currently using react navigation 4.0 versions. But the above one is solve in a another way like


In my Dashboard.js Screen and HomeScreen.js "Login" i used this way

import {AuthContext} from '../../Routes';

and also now const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext); and now this context interlink to the route.js so it works well with the dispatch.

Comment: Now i am facing a recycle issue warning.

In route.js above i am already having authcontext which i am accessing in homescreen.js and dashboard.js

import {AuthContext} from '../../Routes';
const { signIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

After this things are working, but i am getting yellow warning about the recycle.